# Custom control creating

Tags: c#, animation, button, custom-controls

How can I make a custom button like in the image below? I searched on Google about custom control, but this is more special, is animated...

[image]

I know that on StackOoverflow are more questions like mine, but it is not a duplicate, I want to learn more about this particular button.

It is a button for WinForms.

Comment: You have to be more specific; is it a button on webpage? XAML button for Wpf or Silverlight? There are tons of sample on button styles and templates out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create these buttons with GDI+ in C#,for example look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19318/Vista-Style-Button-in-C) one

Answer (score 1):

On Windows form these buttons are made using the [BackgroundImage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx) of Button Control.
 
All you need is to toggle the background image on events like [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx),[OnMouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y878dt5.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a custom control, this is CSS

Have a look at this, http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css_square_buttons/

You should possibly read something about gif-animation, jquery animation or css3 transitions to be able to animate backgrounds of such element

Comment: This is not to be made in CSS I think, it is a button for WinForms, sorry 'cause I forgot to mention that.